# The Assignment Operator in R: Does "<-" work all the time, in comparison to "="?

Tags: r

In R, I have come across an example in which both `=` and `<-` are valid for assignment. e.g.

```
> y = c("hello", "world")
> y
[1] "hello" "world"
> y2 <- c("hello", "world")
> y2
[1] "hello" "world"
```

I have also come across an example in which `=` is invalid and `<-` is valid. e.g.

```
> quote(y[1] <- 1)
y[1] <- 1
> quote(x[1] = 1)
Error: unexpected '=' in "quote(x[1] ="
```

My question is, are there any cases in which the vice versa is true? i.e. `<-` is invalid whilst `=` is valid?

Reason for asking this question is to understand whether to stick with `=`, `<-`, or either (depending on circumstances) when performing assignment operation in R.

This will really help me setting up my mindset when performing coding in R.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R has several assignment operators. Per [the documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assignOps.html)

> The operator `<-` can be used anywhere, whereas the operator `=` is only allowed at the top level (e.g., in the complete expression typed at the command prompt) or as one of the subexpressions in a braced list of expressions.

The only place I am aware of where you must use the `<-` operator is naming items of a list in attach.

This does not work:

```
> attach(what <- list(foo <- function(x) print(x)))
```

but this does:

```
> attach(what <- list(foo = function(x) print(x)))
```

I don't actually know why this is. If anyone else knows I'd love to learn why.

I am also compelled to discourage use of any of the blasphemous right assignment operators.

Comment: `attach(what = list(foo = function(x) print(x)))` would be passing argument `what` with value `list(foo = function(x) print(x))` to `attach()`, which has a `what` argument. But the subtlety is that you never create an object `what`. The version using `<-` does: basically what you are doing is creating an object `what`, which is then attached as `what` is passed to the `what` argument.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I take your point, but I don't see how this affects the assignment within the list. I'm not sure what it is about lists that prevents this from working: `attach(what = list(foo <- function(x) print(x)))`

Comment: And `what` ended up without names because of `<-`

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood what you were showing. Why this `attach(what = list(foo <- function(x) print(x)))` fails is obvious. You are making the contents of a list available via their names and yet you've created a list without any names - run `list(foo <- function(x) print(x))` on it's own and you see this.

Comment: @GavinSimpson of course! That makes a lot of sense. I can't believe I never realized this before.

Comment: Thank you @user12202013 for presenting an example in which `=` works and `<-` doesn't. And thank you everybody for helping out! I now understand `=` is for local argument assignment whereas `<-` is for global variable assignment, which I did not know before.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse yourself. Use `<-` when you assign a value to a variable, use `=` when setting a function's arguments. This, I believe, is the clearest way of doing things easily and normally and doing what you most probably want to do.

**Assignment using `<-` as opposed to `=`**

I'm defining a function

```
temp <- function(arg)
    2*arg
```

Let's call it:

```
temp(arg = 2)
[1] 4
temp(arg <- 2)
[1] 4
```

Seems it is the same, but is it?

Let us print arg:

```
arg ## first case
Error: object 'arg' not found
arg ## second case
[1] 2
```

Weird, isn't it? You most probably didn't want to store that value to that variable, but it happened, because you used `<-`.

Comment: Thank you @naltipar. This is a great example of usage of "<-" vs "=". So temp(arg <- 2)  assign 2 to arg globally to the entire R program. Whereas temp(arg = 2) assign 2 to arg locally within the temp() scope. (I didn't know that! ;)

Comment: … or you could simply always use `=` and ignore that `<-` exists.